# Hibernate: One table, multiple entity/persist class, is it legal?

Tags: java, hibernate

If multiple entity/persist class instance OWN the some record of one table.

then what happend(suppose in a multithreaded application)? Is it legal in Hibernate?

Comment: Did you try it? What *does* happen?

Answer (score 2):

Yes It is **legal** to have more than one entity for single table. This is the problem called      **[Granularity](http://hibernate.org/orm/what-is-an-orm/)**.

Hope This is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by own? A composition of `P` owning `C` using `UML` semantics? If so, you should have an unique constraint defined on the table, `P` is mapped to. In addition, you should map the property of `P` holding `C`, with **cascade=”delete”**. With all this in place, one thread should succeed in persisting `C`, owned by many threads in terms of having different `P`s owning the same `C`. All the others should fail to commit, because of the unique constraint defined.